# Check if month is in interval in c# (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I am developping an application where a user can download various reports. There is one report per month and each report is called "YYYY-MM.txt". An user can only download files of the last 18 months.

I have written a function that takes in parameter a list of filespath and then downloading them to the client. My problem is how to add files in this list, basically how can   I check if a file is in the last 18 months, knowing that I have his year and month, and the current year and month.

This is what I have :

```
 //just for test, supposed that theses values were extracted from the report of august 2014.
        string fileYear = "2014";
        string fileMonth = "08";

        string currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        string currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
```

How can I compare fileYear and fileMonth with currentYear and currentMonth to know if the report correspond to a month of the last 18.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it.

```
int fileYear = int.Parse(fileName.Substring(0,4));
int fileMonth = int.Parse(fileName.Substring(5,2));

DateTime oldestDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-18);
int oldestYear = oldestDate.Year;
int oldestMonth = oldestDate.Month;

if(fileYear > oldestYear || (fileYear == oldestYear && fileMonth >= oldestMonth))
{
    // This file is within 18 months.
}
```

This means that if today is 12-31-2014 it will include files back to 2013-06.txt.  If needed you can also put an upper bounds check in case you could have files with future dates.

EDIT

The other alternative is to create a `DateTime` from the file name to compare.  Here's how I would do that to ensure I'm comparing the last day of the file's month

```
int fileYear = int.Parse(fileName.Substring(0,4));
int fileMonth = int.Parse(fileName.Substring(5,2));
DateTime fileDate = new DateTime(fileYear, fileMonth, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
DateTime oldestDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-18);
if(fileDate.Date >= oldestDate.Date)
{
    // This file is within 18 months.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/VORvZr

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime fileDate = new DateTime(2013, 5, 1);
        DateTime fileDateNewer = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);

        GetMonthDifference(fileDate);
        GetMonthDifference(fileDateNewer);
    }

    public static void GetMonthDifference(DateTime fileDate)
    {
        DateTime currentDate =  DateTime.Now;
        DateTime eighteenMonthsAgo = currentDate.AddMonths(-18);

        if (eighteenMonthsAgo > fileDate)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is greater than or equal to 18 months ago", fileDate);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is less than 18 months ago", fileDate);
    }
}
```

Note that if you can, you always want to try to work with objects that most closely represent your data.  E.g. if working with years you should work with a numeric type rather than string type.  In this case, working with dates.

EDIT:

as comments posted on the other answers pointed out, you would have some room for error depending on the *day* the file was uploaded/created if it's right around the 18 month mark.  Something you could potentially do is get the actual file creation date (assuming you are the system creating the file and the date of the file creation coincides with the month the data belongs.  You can get a files creation date as such:

```
string fullFilePathAndName = @""; // wherever your file is located
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fullFilePathAndName);
DateTime fileCreateDate = fi.CreationTime
```

Comment: Personally it makes more sense to assume that one file per month means the end of the month and not the beginning.

Comment: agreed - though it seems like you're going to be making an assumption *somewhere*.  I was just using the DateTimes with the 1st day of the month as an example.